# Call web service methods in specific order

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I have two web service calls, Method1() and Method2().

If a boolean variable is set to true, Method1() should be called first, then Method2().
If the boolean variable is set to false, only Method2() should be called.

When I look at the timestamps of the xml files, I can see that request/response of Method1() have a newer timestamp than files for Method2(), which suggest that Method2 is called before Method1.

Is there a way to wait for Method1() to complete before Method2() gets called?

```
    var client = new WebServiceClient();

    bool myBoolean = true;

    if (myBoolean)
    { 
        XmlHandler.ToXML(method1Request, "C:/Temp/method1RQ.xml");
        var method1Response = client.Method1(method1Request);
        XmlHandler.ToXML(method1Response, "C:/Temp/method1RS.xml");
    }

    XmlHandler.ToXML(method2Request, "C:/Temp/method2RQ.xml");
    var method2Response = client.Method2(method2Request);
    XmlHandler.ToXML(method2Response, "C:/Temp/method2RS.xml");

    client.Close();
```

Code in XmlHandler:

```
public static void ToXML(object obj, string savePath)
{
    if (obj != null)
    {
        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(savePath))
            {
                File.Delete(savePath);
            }
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
            using (XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(savePath, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, obj);
                xmlWriter.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using synchronous calls, so I don't really see how what you describe could be happening. Please show the log.

Comment: Exactly, I don't understand why it's happening either. I have simplified the code a little bit here, but what I do is to write an xml to file for request/response of Method1() call and request/response of Method2() call. When I then look at the timestamp of the xml's, I see that files for Method1() have time 09:30:24, and Method2() have time 09:30:23, which suggest that Method2() is called before Method1().

Comment: @bale3; A possible cause for the timestamp mismatch. Depending on the ToXML implementation, if the underlying filestream isn't correctly disposed/flushed, there is no way in telling which file gets flushed to the file system last.
Also, You could fire up the debugger in both the client and server and verify the order of program execution.

Comment: +1 on MarkO, I just added the same in my answer. You could change your code to explicitly write the XML with a file stream and call Dispose on the stream writer so that you get definied behaviour.

Comment: these are synchronous calls so the order is defined. However from a design perspective you might want to create additional service methods for each of boolean case like `MethodX{Method1(); Method2();}`

Answer (score 0):

> > Is there a way to wait for Method1() to complete before Method2() gets called?

That is the default behaviour with synchronous calls, which you are using.

My best guess is that you have fired off two service clients concurrently.

Look at the server logs to see when the calls came in.

It could also be that you are looking at a timestamps on local files that were flushed as a result of finalization at the end of the program, so the timing / order is undefined.

I'm not familiar with XmlHandler, but whatever XmlHandler is doing internally, make sure to Close, Flush and/or Dispose the StreamWriters.

Comment: I'm using the same service client instance for both methods.

Comment: Hmm, then I'd look at the server logs to see when the calls came in. It could be that you are looking at a timestamp on a file that was flushed as a result of finalization at the end of the program, so the timing is undefined.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the server logs as it is an external web service, but I think I'm handling the disposing of the streamwriter correctly. See my updated OP.